# Apply a function to all combinations of rows from one df and columns from another df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

This problem is structurally like multiplying a row and column vector to produce a matrix, and then summarizing the rows of the resulting matrix.

Except in the row vector each element has two values A and B, and in the column vector each element has two values X and Y.  And instead of multiplication, the operation is evaluating a function of A, B, X and Y.

The following code accomplishes the goal.  But is there a way to do it without the loop and resorting to iterrows()?  In the real problem the row vector has thousands of elements and the column vector can have millions.

```
from numpy import sin, cos, exp, nan 
from numpy.random import random

# Sample function that can operate on ndarrays
def myfun(a, b, x, y):
    return sin(a+x), exp(b+y) 

# sort of a "row vector"
df_ab = pd.DataFrame(random([2,6]), 
                     index=['A','B'],
                     columns=['AB%d'%i for i in range(6)])
# sort of a "column vector"
df_xy = pd.DataFrame(random([8,2]), 
                     columns=['X','Y'],
                     index=['XY%d'%i for i in range(8)])

# pre-add columns for the summarized results
df_xy['SUM_FUN0'] = nan
df_xy['SUM_FUN1'] = nan

# for each pair of values X,Y
for _, xy in df_xy.iterrows():
    # calculate myfun with each pair of values A,B
    funout0, funout1 = myfun(df_ab.loc['A'], df_ab.loc['B'], xy.X, xy.Y)
    # summarize and store the result
    xy['SUM_FUN0'] = funout0.sum()
    xy['SUM_FUN1'] = funout1.sum()
```

Comment: how many rows in your data? one improvement which could speed it up is assigning `db_ab.loc['A']` and `db_ab.loc['B']` to variables outside the `for` loop, so that you aren't repeating `df.loc` functionality.

Comment: df_ab will have a small number of rows, less than 10, but thousands of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? I haven't tested performance, but `apply` is usually marginally better than `iterrows`.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import sin, cos, exp, nan, sum
from numpy.random import random
from numba import jit

# Sample function that can operate on ndarrays
@jit(nopython=True)
def myfun(a, b, x, y):
    return sum(sin(a+x)), sum(exp(b+y))

# sort of a "row vector"
df_ab = pd.DataFrame(random([2,6]), 
                     index=['A','B'],
                     columns=['AB%d'%i for i in range(6)])

# sort of a "column vector"
df_xy = pd.DataFrame(random([8,2]), 
                     columns=['X','Y'],
                     index=['XY%d'%i for i in range(8)])

A = df_ab.loc['A'].values
B = df_ab.loc['B'].values

df_xy['SUM_FUN0'], df_xy['SUM_FUN1'] = list(zip(*df_xy.apply(lambda x: myfun(A, B, x['X'], x['Y']), axis=1)))
```

Comment: Thanks! There are a couple of interesting ideas here for me to try on the real problem.  Do you have any more substantial observations about what influences performance here?

Comment: @adr, main observations are: (1) `apply` is just a thinly veiled loop, but faster than `iterrows`, (2) retrieving `A` and `B` repeatedly can be costly - just do once if possible, (3) `numba.jit` optimizes most `numpy` functions by JIT-compiling, but requires all inputs to be `numpy` friendly.

Comment: Still hoping for more ideas, although hope is dwindling.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's all the ideas there are.  My eyes have been opened to how slow pandas can be: (2) had by far the biggest impact on execution time both in the example and in the real problem.